# Php curl set ssl version

Tags: php, curl, handshake, sslv3

Since 3 days I can't connect to the paypal sandbox. I found out that they maybe dissabled the support for SSLv3. So i tried to change the SSL Version in my curl Request by setting :

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,1); # 1 = TLSv1
```

But it still give me the same error :

```
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Any idea why the script is still using SSLv3 ?

I am using php 5.5 and the following curl version ( currently asking at my hoster [ managed hosting at 1&1 ] to upgrade to a newer version)

curl 7.21.0 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.15 libssh2/1.2.6
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that PayPal dropped support for SSLv3, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 and now only support TLS 1.2 but the OpenSSL version cURL is built with (`0.9.8o`) does not support TLS.

At this point all you can do is hope the host can update OpenSSL, cURL, and PHP to a newer (1.0+) version of OpenSSL.

As it stands now, your cURL client doesn't speak TLS which is required by PayPal and there are no ways around it other than updating OpenSSL.

Comment: The only solution is to upgrade to a newer CURL version that includes OpenSSL 1.0+. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 4):

Had same issue.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');

$response =    curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($response);
exit;
```

response:

```
bool(false)
```

and no error logs!

So I've made small script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
var_dump(file_get_contents('https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp'));
```

and here what I've got in logs:

```
[12-Feb-2016 15:56:19] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure in /xxx/yyy.php on line 3
[12-Feb-2016 15:56:19] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /xxx/yyy.php on line 3
[12-Feb-2016 15:56:19] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp): failed to open stream: operation failed in /xxx/yyy.php on line 3
```

My solution was:

1. Update (1.0+) version of OpenSSL.
2. Recompile Curl
3. Recompile PHP with new CURL
4. Make sure Curl SSL Version is OpenSSL/(1.0+)

> SSL Version   OpenSSL/1.0.1e  – Good
>
> SSL Version   NSS/3.13.6.0  – Bad

I am running on CentOS. Here what I did to update:

1. Update OpenSSL:

   openssl version

if below 1.0 run: yum update openssl
make sure it is actually updated

2. Reinstall PHP. So save php.ini file
3. Keep a list of all PHP modules installed via:

   yum list installed | grep php

**save output!**

4. yum erase php
5. yum erase php-curl
6. yum install php
7. yum install php-curl
8. restart apache or fpm and if you are lucky you'll get things working
9. restore php.ini configs and PHP modules: yum install php-pgsql; yum install php-gd; etc

However if your package repositories outdated or you have curl library installed with NSS SSL bindings you can download and compile curl library manually. I've used **phpize** tool bundled with the php-devel package. So my problem I've had:

```
cURL Information    7.19.7 
SSL Version     NSS/3.13.6.0
```

and here is how I've changed it to:

```
cURL Information    7.22.0 
SSL Version     OpenSSL/1.0.1e
```

1. Update OpenSSL:

   openssl version

if below 1.0 run: yum update openssl
make sure it is actually updated

2. Reinstall PHP. So save php.ini file
3. Keep a list of all PHP modules installed via:

   yum list installed | grep php

**save output!**

4. yum erase php
5. yum erase php-curl
6. yum install php-devel
7. print PHP version with **rpm -qa --queryformat '%{version}' php** and find where you can download exact same PHP sources
8. Following bash script will install specific curl library:

```html
<pre>
#!/bin/bash

PHP_VERSION=$(rpm -qa --queryformat '%{version}' php)

CURL_VERSION=7.22.0

#echo $CURL_VERSION
#exit

#wget --no-check-certificate http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/php/php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.gz -O /tmp/php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.gz
wget --no-check-certificate http://museum.php.net/php5/php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.gz -O /tmp/php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.gz
wget --no-check-certificate http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-${CURL_VERSION}.tar.gz -O /tmp/curl-${CURL_VERSION}.tar.gz

cd /tmp; tar xzf php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.gz
cd /tmp; tar xzf curl-${CURL_VERSION}.tar.gz

cd curl-${CURL_VERSION}
./configure
make
make install

cd /tmp; rm -rf curl-${CURL_VERSION}*

sleep 2

cd /tmp/php-${PHP_VERSION}/ext/curl/
phpize
./configure
make
make install

cd /tmp; rm -rf php-${PHP_VERSION}*

</pre>
```

8. restart apache or fpm and if you are lucky you'll get things working
9. restore php.ini configs and PHP modules: yum install php-pgsql; yum install php-gd; etc

Answer (score 1):

Perfect, I wanted LibCurl to use OpenSSL instead of NSS, this has helped me fix it to tweak the php libcurl to use OpenSSL.

My Centos7 PHP 5.6 was using

```
php -r "print_r(curl_version());" | grep ssl_version
[ssl_version_number] => 0
[ssl_version] => NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC
```

and after the above fix, it shows, this is what I wanted.

```
php -r "print_r(curl_version());" | grep ssl_version
[ssl_version_number] => 0
[ssl_version] => OpenSSL/1.0.1f
```

Here is the revised script that I have used on Centos7 with PHP 5.6.17

```
#!/bin/bash
PHP_VERSION=$(rpm -qa --queryformat '%{version}' php56)
CURL_VERSION=$(curl -V|head -1|awk '{print $2}')
wget --no-check-certificate http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/php/php-5.6.17.tar.bz2 -O /tmp/php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.bz2
wget --no-check-certificate http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-${CURL_VERSION}.tar.gz -O /tmp/curl-${CURL_VERSION}.tar.gz

cd /tmp; tar xjf php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.bz2
cd /tmp; tar xzf curl-${CURL_VERSION}.tar.gz

cd curl-${CURL_VERSION}
./configure
make
make install

cd /tmp; rm -rf curl-${CURL_VERSION}*

sleep 2

cd /tmp/php-${PHP_VERSION}/ext/curl/
phpize
./configure
make
make install

cd /tmp; rm -rf php-${PHP_VERSION}*
```