# Curl error: SSL connect error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal

When i try to make payment using Paypal api it generate this error 
'Curl error: SSL connect error' 
- PHP version 5.4 
but same code work in my local machine and i have PHP 5.6 in local machine 
- is there version issue with this or somethings else ?

- my curl code is

  ```
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_string);
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
  {
     echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'Curl Execuation Success...';
     } 
  curl_close($curl);
  ```

Comment: What generates the error? PayPal or is that an error which PHP's cURL is showing?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus i just update my code... i don't know what cause this issue. this same code work for me in my local machine.

Comment: Try adding curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 3);

Comment: I see, please see my answer

Comment: is it related to my hosting or its paypal api issue. please let me help if anyone ever get this kind of issue.

Comment: I may be related to your hosting bu there is more chance that is just related to your SSL configuration. Did you try my previsou suggestions ?

Comment: @MonleyZeus thank for comment.i just check your comment and update my code. it return 35 error No and tha is  "CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR"

Comment: @Maher Please see my update

Comment: @Maher What is the output of `echo '<pre>'.print_r(curl_version(), TRUE).'</pre>';`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131590/php-curl-set-ssl-version/35136600#35136600) is probably the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the actual error code with

```
echo curl_errno($curl); // It might display a '59'
```

Find '59' at https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html which is **CURLE_SSL_CIPHER (59)** and read about the error and then research how to fix it.

---

**Possible fix**

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073567 you should try:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

This is potentially dangerous though, since it forces SSL3.

Comment: I commented with the same value but it could (should ?) be 6 (CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2, this is TLS v1.2

Comment: @Loenix I wonder if OP's PHP/cURL/openSSL version doesn't support the latest protocol. Maybe PayPal's API requirements are too high for PHP 5.4?